# Как реверснуть список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

```
first = [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]
second = first.reverse()
print(first, second)
```

Выводит "`[0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0] None`", а не "`[0, 1, 0, 3, 0 , 3, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0]`". Как исправить и почему так происходит?

Comment: `second = list(reversed(first))` или `second = first[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что метод `first.reverse()` инвертирует свой объект, не возвращая ничего. Чтобы получить необходимый результат, необходимо не менять первый объект, а скопировать его значение, инвертируя порядок его членов. Как сделать данную операцию, уже ответил @Natig Agharzayev, но он не объяснил, как это работает.

Answer (score 3):

метод `reverse` изменяет оригинальный список, поэтому результат сохранять не надо

```
arr = [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]
arr.reverse()
print(arr)
```

чтобы получить развернутый список можно использовать метод `reversed`:

```
reversed_arr = list(reversed(arr))
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы у меня получился список, который я изменяю, и  список, строящийся как имеющийся, но в обратном порядке

Answer (score 0):

```
first = [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]
second = first[::-1]
print(first, second)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]